# Prevent line breaks before or after `<a>` tag

Tags: html, css

I have an ebook which contains a code like:

```
Some text (<a id="aref"></a>Some more text) that continues
```

I need the anchor to refer to this part of the text in the index. However, the tag allows line breaks, so I often end up with a line break right after `(`.

Is there a way to prevent these line breaks (putting the anchor before the `(` is not an option).

Comment: Can you wrap a tag around the `(` and the anchor? For example: `<span style="white-space:nowrap;">(<a id="aref"></a></span>Some more text)`.

Comment: Also, which ebook reader are you seeing this issue in?

Comment: "putting the anchor before the ( is not an option" Why? Are you really using it as hyperlink or do you only need an anchor within the page?

Comment: @bfrohs: This is using EPUB with Aldiko. Now that I've tried a bit more, I don't seem to be able to reproduce with other ebook readers, so it might as well be a bug in Aldiko…

Comment: What do you mean "the tag allows line breaks"? Are you saying there is whitespace or a new line between `(` and the next character in the source code? If so, then there's not much you can do if you can't touch the HTML.

Comment: Raphink, check to see if there is a non-visible character preset between the `(` and `<` (delete both characters and retype them). That might fix the bug. But yes, it appears to be a bug in Aldiko. Try my solution in the first comment to work around it.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: Not in the source code. The two characters are touching, but Aldiko allows a line break between them.

Comment: @bfrohs: No, the two characters are really touching in the code.

Comment: @bfrohs: Unfortunately, the way it's generated makes it rather hard to insert an element around the parenthesis.

Comment: Raphink, are you able to move the tag to a spot where there's a space? E.g., after `Some`. That's about all I can think of for a workaround.

Comment: @bfrohs: No. To be clear, I generate this ebook from LaTeX, with `Some text (\acommand) that continues` and `\acommand` shouldn't know about the brackets. I did report the bug to the Aldiko team though, we'll see if they fix it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely a bug in Aldiko. I have reported it and am waiting for them to fix it.

Answer (score 11):

Make your anchor tag inline using the CSS property `display: inline`, for example:

```
 <a style="display: inline;" >
```

Comment: @WesleyMurch, in compliant applications, yes. But 1) it can be changed by other code, and 2) this application may have a bug.

Comment: @WesleyMurch if you read the original post, you'll see that this isn't just plain HTML. The poster is writing an ebook so I suspect there's code that's changing the defaults.

Comment: 2021 this does not work anymore

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be breaking at all unless you've added css to do so.

Try:

```
display: inline;
clear: none;
```